# How to interactively embed web page into PowerPoint or OneNote documents?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-office-2013

Is it possible to **embed a webpage interactively** into Microsoft Office **Powerpoint presentation** and into **OneNote page**?

By **interactively** I mean:

- I enter URL which has to be loaded.
- I can navigate in its frame within the page.

The concept is similar to `iframe` usage on web.